# How to pass table name as variable in to PostgreSQL query in python 3 code and prevent SQL injection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, odoo

I'm working with Odoo 13 and in a wizard (models.TransientModel) file I need to execute a PostgreSQL query to fetch some data based on the values of the fields selected by wizard view. I was to told to write the query in a way to prevent SQL Injection.This is the way I tried to handle this, but there's an error.

```
active_model = tools.ustr(context.get('active_model').replace('.', '_'))
        self._cr.execute("""select hr_employee_id from %s where active='t' and id in %s
                         """, (active_model, (tuple(context.get('active_ids')),)))
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'assignment_assignment'"
LINE 1: select hr_employee_id from 'assignment_assignment' where act...
```

The above code return the parameter plus an extra single quotation which breaks the query. I solved the problem using bellow code:

```
active_model = tools.ustr(context.get('active_model').replace('.', '_'))
self._cr.execute("select hr_employee_id from " + active_model + " where active='t' and id in %s", (tuple(context.get('active_ids')),))
```

But I'm not sure how much correct it is and how safe it is against SQL Injection. Therefor, I'm wonder to know how can I handle above code in a safe way to prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: Why not using Odoo's ORM layer? You should have everything for it: `self.env[active_model].browse(context.get('active_ids', [])).read(['hr_employee_id'])`

Comment: Because I can't pass the model name (active_model)  in a single quotation to the self.env['']  and can't use all the feature. Can you tell me how to pass a variable in self.evn as the value. Because the variable name is the model name to pass the self.env.